# Any javascript libraries to render 2d keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I want to 2-d render every single key of my keyboard on a web-app. So, if I do a keypress, it will visibly show that on the web page. Are there any particular js libraries to achieve such a thing? If not, what would be the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be useful

Demo
http://jabtunes.com/notation/keyboardcanvasexamples.html

Source
http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2010/02/06/online-virtual-keyboard-with-canvas-and-javascript/